# Are Universal Links cached in iOS? Do they work offline?

Tags: ios, security, https, ios-universal-links, applinks

I tested Universal Links in iOS by turning on Airplane mode and saw that the correct application was opened (instead of a website)

This indicates some level of "caching" the `apple-app-site-association`.

I want to determine the extent to which this is cached, so I can determine

- What UX edge cases are there (e.g. Offline for x days)
- What security considerations are there (e.g. MITM / SSLStrip + .well-known/URL)

etc.

Ideally I would like to have details if additional logic is employed (conditional caching if HTTPS employed, DNSSec, etc)

Answer (score 37):

The exact behavior here is (intentionally?) unclear from Apple. Here is my personal experience, gleaned partly from official documentation and partly from helping thousands of apps implement Universal Links at [Branch.io](https://branch.io).

- The `apple-app-site-association` file is cached *once* when the app is first installed.
- If this initial scrape fails, in almost all situations it will not be reattempted. The only exception to this is if the initial return is a 5xx error, in which case a limited number of retries may occur. This is not well-documented, and is not covered in Universal Links documentation at all. You can find a mention in the [Shared Web Credentials docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/1654440-shared_web_credentials).
- The file is *not* checked at all when a Universal Link is opened. This is why you are able to get Universal Links behavior in airplane mode.
- The file does not expire. Once it is cached, it sticks permanently for as long as the app is installed.
- The file will be re-checked when installing an app update.
- The file must be accessible via a valid SSL connection at either `https://example.com/apple-app-site-association` or `https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`. If there are redirects of any kind, this will fail.
- It is theoretically possible to MITM the request if you are able to install a new SSL certificate directly on the device in question. [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com) for example uses this approach for debugging. I have never seen or heard of this being exploited, and the damage would be quite limited because the domain still has to be specified inside the app itself.

Comment: Alex, I would consider Branch.IO for my project, but under no condition can my data travel to your servers.  If you had a more private solution I could be interested in Branch

Comment: That depends greatly on what you would classify as 'data'. We have a number of [high profile brands](https://branch.io/partners/) using the Branch service, so data privacy and security are taken very seriously. A common approach is using the link as a delivery mechanism for an encrypted token referencing the data on your own backend, instead of storing the data itself in the link. Feel free to [get in contact](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) if you want to talk through any specific concerns!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get around the caching issue. The cache is bound to the domain name, so for every time you want iOS to request `apple-app-site-association` you can create a new subdomain, and configure iOS to use that subdomain as the universal link for your app.

Extremely hacky, but it is the only workaround that worked for me.

Comment: If you are updating your app, apple says they will fetch the aasa file within 24 hours. Otherwise, it is supposed to be re-downloaded after 7 days https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/supporting-associated-domains